# Calling an Javascript function after adding an item

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I have an javascript function to display div block once i added any item to cart. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: what kind of functionality you want in that javascript function.

Comment: Once add to cart button clicked, i need to display cart modal window

Comment: after completing add action your page moving to shopping cart page or stay on the same page like ajax? from both place listing and details page?

Comment: staying on the same page. added screenshot for reference

Answer (score 0):

For this you can refer http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/04/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax/ this url or some of the free extension are also available for this like

1) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-popup.html

2) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-add-to-cart-4.html

3) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-mini-cart-ajax-cart.html

4) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-filter-and-cart-1.html

Hope this will help you.